# Adding a subview releases properties of parent view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am adding a subview (childView) on main view controller (parentView) for selection of some options from the menu. But when I remove it from the view, the properties of parent view returns null. Can anybody explain this behavior. Also I am using ARC.

This is how I am adding subview:

```
resolutionPopUp=[ResolutionPopUp alloc];
resolutionPopUp.resPopStr = combinedUrl;
[self.view addSubview:resolutionPopUp.view];
```

And when I remove the subview using:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

all the properties of the existing view controller returns null.

Comment: Show us some code and we'll see what we can do to help.

Comment: WHat kind of property is the childView ?

Comment: the child view is UIViewController

Comment: Show us how you're removing the subview.

Comment: Can you post the code where you declared the view property?

Answer (score 0):

`[self.view removeFromSuperview]` removes the parent view from its parent (which will be a `UIWindow`) and results in `self.view` being garbaged collected. The correct way to remove the subview, `resolutionPopUp.view` is this:

```
[resolutionPopUp.view removeFromSuperview];
```

This is will remove `resolutionPopUp.view` from `self.view`.

Comment: it is not working. The subview does not get removed now.

Comment: Where are you trying to remove the view: in the parent view controller or the child view controller?

Comment: in the child view controller

Comment: If the child view controller will remove its view from its parent, then `[self.view removeFromSuperview]` is the right way to do it. If the parent view controller wants to remove the view of its child view controller, then `[resolutionPopUp.view removeFromSuperview]` is the right way. If neither of those are doing what you expect, then there's some detail in what you are doing that you've not mentioned that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

self.view is your parentViewController.and you are removing that so this is main reason why you are getting null Value.
instead of that,user

```
     resolutionPopUp=[ResolutionPopUp alloc];
      resolutionPopUp.resPopStr = combinedUrl;
       [self.view addSubview:resolutionPopUp.view];
      [resolutionPopUp.view removeFromSuperView];
```

this is correct way.